# Trying to get video thumb nail using VueJS3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to develop a straightforward program that will allow me to get movies from my AWS-S3 bucket and convert them to picture thumbnails.

Here is my code.

```
<template>
   <img :src="imgURL" class="card-top" alt="thumb_nail">   
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const imgURL = ref("")
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    video.src = props.url;
    video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);

      imgURL.value = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    })
    return { url: props.url, imgURL };
  },
});
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
   <Thumbnail  src="aws-s3_bucket_url" />   
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import Thumbnail from "../components/Thumbnail.vue"
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Thumbnail
  }
  });
</script>
```

There are no errors in the code, the picture does not appear. It has its height and width, but the picture does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the url is valid and that `loadeddata` event fires.

You can test with a test video url to ensure that it loads.

```html
<template>
  <!-- parent.vue -->
  <VideoComponent url="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" />
</template>
```

If this example show you something that means that the provided prop is not a valid url when you load your data.

If it doesn't you are not rendering this component properly.

Comment: I already have this component imported in my Home.vue

Comment: Please show the Home component too